# Mac mini running Catalina has no sound input

Tags: audio, mac-mini, microphone

I have my Blue Snowball plugged directly into a USB on the back of my Mac Mini. The light indicating power to my mic is showing. I didn't find any input devices in preferences, even the built-in mic. I did an NVRAM reset and nothing happened. I tried going into safe mode and creating another administrator account to find a sound input device, that didn't work.

Comment: Where are you looking for sound input?

Answer (score 1):

`Apple Menu > System Preferences > Sound` is the place to look for Input Sources:

I've selected the Internal Microphone in the screenshot below for legibility. To use the Snowball mic (an amazing mic, BTW,) just select it. You can adjust the input volume, too.

[image]